# passing command as argument in bash

Tags: bash

I have a simple script that takes the first argument from the command line and prints `hello, first_arg`.

But when I pass `|ls`,  it is printing files in the current directory.

My script file

```sh
#! /bin/bash

echo "Hello, $1."
```

I tried multiple things

- `echo "Hello, '$'"`
- `echo "Hello," "$1"`
- `printf "Hello %s" "$1"`

I want output like `Hello, |ls`

I checked quoting and this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells

### Edit

but It is not happening with input like

```sh
echo "input: "
read name
echo "Hello, $name."  # output Hello, |ls
echo "Hello, " $name  # output Hello, |ls
```

Comment: Simply quote `"|ls"` on the command line to prevent expansion (piping to `ls`)  by the shell. E.g. `bash yourscript "|ls"` (single or double quotes are fine here)

Comment: If you invoke the script with quotes around the argument, as in `script '|ls'`, it will work.  If you don't use single or double quotes, then the command line is read as 'output of your script piped to `ls`', and `ls` doesn't read its standard input.  So the problem is not inside the script — it is all in how you invoke it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Is there any way to handle it in the script?

Comment: No. The expansion is preformed by the shell when your script is invoked. Meaning the shell would have already set up to pipe the result of your script to `ls` before the script was even started. By quoting the argument you tell the shell to treat it as a string (and argument to your script) and not further shell expressions.

Comment: oh. Now I got it. Thanks, @DavidC.Rankin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the pipe when invoking the script. Otherwise the shell will arrange for the standard output your script to be sent standard input of `ls` and you will end up with the output as if you hand run `ls` on it's own. Either of these would do:

```
./simple.sh \|ls
./simple.sh '|ls'
./simple.sh "|ls"
```